# An error about TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I tried to correct English grammar by running a model.

My development environment is `Linux` + `Anaconda3` + `Python 3.6` + `CUDA 9.0` + `tensorflow1.9.0`

After I ran the model, there was the following problem with the test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./generate.py", line 236, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "./generate.py", line 93, in main
    fluency_scorer = FluencyScorer(args.lang_model_path, args.lang_model_data)
  File "/home/gpower/zhangtianjiu/NLP/pytorch-human-performance-gec-master/fairseq-scripts/fluency_scorer.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.task = tasks.setup_task(self.args)
  File "/home/gpower/zhangtianjiu/NLP/pytorch-human-performance-gec-master/fairseq/fairseq/tasks/__init__.py", line 19, in setup_task
    return TASK_REGISTRY[args.task].setup_task(args)
  File "/home/gpower/zhangtianjiu/NLP/pytorch-human-performance-gec-master/fairseq/fairseq/tasks/language_modeling.py", line 90, in setup_task
    dictionary = Dictionary.load(os.path.join(args.data, 'dict.txt'))
  File "/home/gpower/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 78, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070036/makemigration-causing-error-typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-objec#answer-66675168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to see some code but it looks like the `a` variable in `a = os.fspath(a)` is of type `NoneType`. The `a` variable should either be a string, bytes or an `os.PathLike` object in order to work with the `os.fspath` function.

You can check the Python documentation on the `os.fspath` function: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fspath)