# makemigration causing error "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database-migration, django-migrations

Running makemigration command inside docker container caused this error, can anyone please help me figure out what the problem is ?

```
python3.7 manage.py makemigrations
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 667, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 611, in open_for_read_by_name
    return open(name,mode)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: Are you able to see what the `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py` has around line 611? `name` is None, `open` expects it to be a filename etc.

Comment: You have a bug in your code, provide us with your view, models & forms for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check absence of `your_app/migrations/__init__.py`

If it's not present django could be throw this exception and the solition in this case

-> add `__init__.py` the execute `python manage.py makemigrations` again

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of [django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3df8ccf6fc3fa0ab2acf9a03da43fea87f8ff392/django/db/migrations/loader.py#L74).

```
from importlib import import_module
import_module('yourapp.migrations')
```

import_module behaviour has changed in python 3.6 (or 3.7, I don't remember).

Either bump your version of django or use python < 3.7