# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not None Type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this code in Pycharm, but I'm getting below error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

This is for windows 10, running on Pycharm, python 3.7

```
import os
import time
file_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), "birth_day_lookup.txt")


def check_birthday():

    lookup_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    today = time.strftime('%d-%B')
    flag = 0
    for entry in lookup_file:
        if today in entry:
            line = entry.split(' ')
            flag = 1
            os.system('notify-send "Today is '+line[1]+' '+line[2]+'\'s Birthday"')
    if flag == 0:
        os.system('notify-send "No birthday for today is listed"')

check_birthday()
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback please?

Comment: what is the output of `print(os.getenv("HOME"))`?

Comment: `HOME` environment variable is not always set in windows: https://superuser.com/questions/607105/is-the-home-environment-variable-normally-set-in-windows

Comment: @eyllanesc output of print(os.getenv("HOME")) would be None

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070036/makemigration-causing-error-typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-objec#answer-66675168

Comment: For me, this error was raised when I updated python 3.6 to 3.8 and running tests on `Django 2.2.8` . Solved it by adding a `__init__.py` file to the tests folder. (It was ok on python 3.6).

Answer (score 7):

Apparently `os.getenv("HOME")` would return a Nonetype value if the environment variable doesn't exist.
Try `os.getenv('HOME', "not found")` to be sure. --gives output as "not found" if the env is not available.
Rather, you can use `os.getcwd()` if the .py file exits in the same directory as birth_day_lookup.txt. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `.condarc` file in location `C:\Users\UserName\`

Answer (score -1):

Python expects that there will be, for example, a string (str) or a PathLike object, which you can read about in the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path

Answer (score -2):

Remove **pycache** folders and try one more again